# Put action on input text change, when the input is filled from another standard

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, onchange

How can I put an action on an input when it's text is changed from another input, such as a *datepicker*, for example. I tried to put the action when I click the date, from datepicker, but it doesn't work.
Any suggestions ?
Here is my code sample :

```
datePicker = $("#birthday").datepicker({
        maxDate : "0d",
        showOtherMonths : true,
        selectOtherMonths : true,
        changeYear : true,
        changeMonth : true,

        onSelect : function(date) {
            validateBirthday;
            alert(date);
        }
    });

$("#birthday").on("keydown keyup click input submit mouseenter focus",
     validateBirthday);
```

On the *keydown*, *keyup*, *click*, *focus* and the other parameters from the *on* function the *validateBirthday* is called. But when the input is filled with the value from the *datepicker*, it isn't, although the alert work. Any ideas why this happens ?

**EDIT**

I did some debugging and I saw that the validateBirthday function from the datepicker's onSelect is executed before the input is filled, and that's why it doesn't work. How can I make it execute after the input is filled ?

Comment: Could you post the validateBirthday code?

Comment: Is that a typo that you are missing braces to invoke function?

Comment: @user2182349 I can, but I don't see how could it help you as I said that the code is working fine when I'm actually writing on the input. It doesn't work when the input is autofilled from the datepicker, but when I focus the input or click it, the function is called again. My goal is to make the function to be called when I press a date from the datepicker.

Comment: @charlietfl I tried with or without braces, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just trigger one of the events the validation handler is bound to:

```
onSelect : function(date) {
       $(this).change();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't quite understand what you're saying.